# WMD Editor preview newline disppears when using CSS reset

Tags: wmd-editor

I added WMD Editor as Stackoverflow does, but I have in my css,

```
* 
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This makes newlines disappear, so there is no more space between lines.

is there anything i can do in css for wmd-preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p {
 margin:0px 0 10px 0; 
 }

I did this, and it's fine now, hooray!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!